# Help reconciling credit card with Amazon

Tags: quicken, reconciling

I use Amazon a lot for business purposes, and so have a pretty large number of orders. However, matching credit card transactions against this is a nightmare. I guess amazon charges your card when they ship, so if you have an order with multiple lines that ship at different times, trying to reconcile the credit card charges against actual amazon orders is well nigh impossible.

Just to clarify, I order the items on my personal credit card, and from that I need to generate an expense report (excluding personal items) which I can then submit to my company for reimbursement.

I'm kind of at the point that I'll just not do that, and order each item individually, these orders are pretty easy to reconcile, but that seems ridiculous.

Does anyone have any solutions on how to do this effectively (and hopefully almost automatically) in Quicken?

FWIW, I found the place you can download an order report to get a bulk list of orders, and from that, I can get the order number and consequently get the invoice printed out pretty easily, but reconciling these multiline orders -- I can seem to find a solution.

Comment: are you an employee of the company? or are you the owner of the company?

Comment: The opposite may be easier.... note which orders are personal and subtract them from the total amount spent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Amazon Prime you can set up a [household](https://www.amazon.com/myh/households?ref=mc_am_sharing_add) to share your Prime benefits with others. You can add the business version of yourself to keep personal and business orders separated. Then you can use their [Order History Reports](https://www.amazon.com/gp/b2b/reports/) to get detailed reports for reconciling.

Comment: According to Amazon's site a household has a 2 adult limitation. My wife and I already have Amazon Household - each with our own account. When setting up the Household account, do you set up the business as a teen?